# How to update the Input box's value property when a button is clicked in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am building an app using Angualr JS.

I want to update the `Restaurant` field when the edit button is clicked. That is for `Spicy Kitchen` when the edit button is clicked it will be `Edit Spicy Kitchen Info` and all the value of the input boxes will be updated automatically.

My screenshot is like below,
[image: Screenshot]

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="restaurant in restaurants">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3>{{restaurant.name}}</h3>
                        <h5>{{restaurant.address}}</h5>
                        <h5><strong>Cuisine Offered</strong> {{restaurant.cuisine}}
                        </h5>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;" ng-click="update(restaurant); editRestaurant(restaurant)">Edit</button>
                    </div>
```

Now the update function is like below,

```
$scope.name = 'Restaurant'
$scope.update = function (restaurant) {
        $scope.name = restaurant.name
        console.log('from update: ', $scope.name)
    }
```

code for input box is below,

```
Name:<input type="text" value="{{name}}" ng-model="name" /></td>
```

When I click the edit button values are coming correctly. I consoled them. But it is not updating. How to do it in Angular JS??

`editRestaurant`is like below,

```
$scope.editRestaurant = function (restaurant) {


        console.log(restaurant)

    }
```

Comment: what is inside editRestaurant?

Comment: you necessarily dont need a separate function to do that remove editRestaruant and what is printed inside  console.log('from update: ', $scope.name); ?

Comment: *"But it is not updating"* .... not updating what? Specific problem is not clear. Create a plunker demo also so we can see the full [mcve]

Comment: @Sajeetharan: then how to do that? I am not calling any functions now. Just by clicking the button I want to update the corresponding fields

Comment: you want to update what?

Comment: @Sajeetharan: When the button beside the `Spicy Kitchen` is clicked the value in the input box(beside `Name`) will be `Spicy Kitchen` . Thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that the view is not updating according to the scope value.
This is typical in angular and you can encounter this problem by triggering a digest cycle using for example a $timeout:

```
$scope.update = function (restaurant) {
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.name = restaurant.name
    console.log('from update: ', $scope.name)
  });
}
```

Dont forget to declare $timeout in your controller

```
.controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope, $timeout)
```